# Building a list with bool() results

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I have the following indexes that I need to compare

```
index_1=(df[number:,1] > high_value).argmax() 
index_2=(df[number:,0] < low_value).argmax()
```

If I run `bool(index_tp > index_sl)`, it will return if the statement is True or False. What I'm trying to achieve here is building a list with all Trues and Falses everytime I add 1 to `number`. How can I build this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably like this (assuming you want `number` to run from first to last row of `df`):

```
your_list = [ (df[number:,1] > high_value).argmax() >
              (df[number:,0] < low_value).argmax()
              for number in range(0, df.shape[0]) ]
```

Comment: That is it! Unfortunetly, this method is way slower than the one I'm using atm. But hey, still counts. Thanks a lot!